# How to display Date to Ext Js Column with Json response

Tags: java, json, hibernate, extjs-mvc

stackoverflow forum member I need some help from you.

I am getting the server response for the startDate in json format as
`"startDate":1328466599000`

I want to display it to my ExtJs column. But I am not able to display it.

My column in which i am displaying StartDate is
`[Ext.Date.format(values.StartDate, "c")]`
and my TaskModel is

```
Ext.define("TaskModel", {
        extend : "Gnt.model.Task",

        // Some custom field definitions
        fields : [
            { name: 'Id', type: 'int', useNull : true, mapping: 'id'},
            { name: 'StartDate', type: 'date', mapping: 'startDate'},
            { name: 'EndDate', type: 'date', mapping: 'endDate', dateFormat: 'MS'},
            { name: 'Priority', defaultValue : 1, mapping: 'priority', dateFormat: 'MS' },
            { name: 'Duration', mapping: 'duration'},
             { name: 'PercentDone', mapping: 'percentDone'},
             { name: 'DurationUnit', mapping: 'durationUnit'},
             { name: 'parentId', mapping: 'parentId', type: 'int'},
             { name: 'Name', mapping: 'taskName'},
             { name: 'index', mapping: 'taskindex'},
             { name: 'depth', mapping: 'depth'},
        ]
    });
```

I am not able to view my startDate I am receiving as response to my Column.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is causing this error? If anyone has a solution to this problem please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have defined the dateformat on the priority column, not startdate column?

Comment: thanks for you reply i did it. by specifying dateFormat as **dateFormat: 'time'**

Answer (score 0):

I did a blog post here: http://peterkellner.net/2011/08/24/getting-extjs-4-date-format-to-behave-properly-in-grid-panel-with-asp-net-mvc3/

sorry for digging up something from a while back but I was just searching for the same thing and ran into my blog post first (before this item)